# Why does the paging of a dataTable not work when filling the data again with Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a jQuery dataTable that depending on the option you select in a previous Select shows you some data or others. By default it shows those of the first option and so far everything is correct.

The problem comes when I select the second option, that the dataTable seems to be unconfigured and shows me all the results in a row without respecting the Paginate, also if I try to sort by name or another field it will show me the first option again. The same is also true if I try to change the table page.

I don't know where the error is.

I attach some images as a sample:

- First option (everything works perfect): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svd66.png)
- On select second option: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5D6n.png) , [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEytB.png)
- If i try to click on tabs 1 to 7 or p.ex. order the column
  *Universitat*automatically shows this (results of the first selector but without respecting the design of the table) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfcJl.png)

**First option selector code:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active no-info" id="tab1default">
          <?php if($isAdmin){ ?>
              <input type="hidden" id="niuProfessor" value="<?php echo $niu; ?>">
              <div class="padding-bottom-20">
                  <select id="selectIfAdmin">
                      <option id="mineAdmin" value="mineAdmin">Les meves Universitats</option>
                      <option id="allAdmin" value="allAdmin">Totes les Universitats</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <!--<div id="showByGrau" class="padding-bottom-20" >
                  <select id="selectGrauAdmin">
                      <option value="-1">Tots els graus </option>
                      <?php foreach($degrees as $degree): ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $degree->codiEstudis; ?>"><?php echo $degree->nomGrau; ?></option>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
              </div>-->
          <?php } ?>
        <div id="acordsTeacherAdmin" class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-hover cell-border display compact" id="dev-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Universitat</th>
                  <!-- <th>Grau</th>-->
                <th>Places</th>
                <th>Mesos</th>
                <th>Període</th>
                  <!--<th>Assignatures</th>-->
                <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="taulaAcordsCoordinador">
              <?php foreach ($agree as $ag): ?>
              <tr >
                <td><?php echo $ag->nomUniversitat; ?></td>
                  <!--<td><?php echo $ag->nomGrau; ?></td>-->
                <td><?php echo $ag->plaçes; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ag->mesos; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $ag->període; ?></td>
                  <!--<td align="center">
                      <a href="#" id="assignaturesp" at="<?php echo $ag->codiConveni; ?>">Opinar</a>
                  </td>-->
                <td align="center">
                  <a href="#" id="publicarp" at="<?php echo $ag->idUniversitat; ?>">Publicar</a> / <a href="#" id="acordp" at="<?php echo $ag->codiConveni; ?>">Acord</a>
               </td>

              </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">

                          </div>
          </div>
          <div id="debug">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Second option code (TaulaAcordsCoordinador.php):**

```
<?php foreach ($agree as $ag): ?>
<tr >
    <td><?php echo $ag->nomUniversitat; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ag->plaçes; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ag->mesos; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ag->període; ?></td>
    <!--<td align="center">
                      <a href="#" id="assignaturesp" at="<?php echo $ag->codiConveni; ?>">Opinar</a>
                  </td>-->
        <td align="center">
            <a href="#" id="publicarp" at="<?php echo $ag->idUniversitat; ?>">Publicar</a> / <a href="#" id="acordp" at="<?php echo $ag->codiConveni; ?>">Acord</a>
        </td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

EventListener:

```
,$(document).on("change", "#selectIfAdmin", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {};
        data.niu = $("#niuProfessor").val();
        data.filtre = $(this).val();

        filtrarAcordsAdmin(data);
})
```

**Function with Ajax call:**

```
function filtrarAcordsAdmin(data){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "perfil.php/" + "filtrarAcordsAdmin",
    data: {"data":JSON.stringify(data)},
    success: function(t, e, c) {
        $("#taulaAcordsCoordinador").html(t);
        /*if(data.filtre === "allAdmin"){$("#showByGrau").css('display','block');}
        else{$("#showByGrau").css('display','none');}*/

    },
    error: function(t, e) {
    }
})}
```

**Perfi.php code:**

```
case 'filtrarAcordsAdmin':
            $actionName = "filtrarAcordsAdmin";
            $data['data'] = $_POST['data'];
            array_push($parameters,$data);
            break;
```

**filtrarAcordsAdmin controller:**

```
public function filtrarAcordsAdmin($parameters){
    $data = json_decode($parameters[0]['data']);

    require_once 'models/TeachersModel.php';
    require_once 'models/ConvenisModel.php';
    $teachersModel = new TeachersModel();
    $convenisModel = new ConvenisModel();

    if($data->filtre == 'mineAdmin'){
        $agree = $teachersModel->getAgreementsTeacher($data->niu);
    }elseif ($data->filtre == 'allAdmin'){
        $agree = $convenisModel->getConvenis();
    }

    $teachersModel->disconnect();
    $convenisModel->disconnect();

    $route = $this->view->show("TaulaAcordsCoordinador.php");
    include($route);
}
```

Both functions *getConvenis()* and `getAgreementsTeacher()` are functions of a model that returns de result of a query into the BD like that:

```
public function getConvenis(){
    try {
        $consulta = $this->db->prepare('SELECT uni.nomUniversitat, uni.idUniversitat, es.nomGrau,co.codiConveni,co.codiCentreEstudis,ce.plaçes,ce.mesos,ce.període
                                        FROM centreestudis ce, universitat_estudisuab un,universitats uni,estudisuab es,conveni co
                                        WHERE ce.codiUniEstudis = un.codiUniEstudis
                                        AND uni.idUniversitat = un.idUniversitat
                                        AND un.codiEstudis = es.codiEstudis
                                        AND co.codiCentreEstudis = ce.codiCentreEstudis
                                        ORDER BY uni.nomUniversitat');
        $consulta->execute();
        $obj = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
    return $obj;   
}

 public function getAgreementsTeacher($niu){
    try {
        $consulta = $this->db->prepare('SELECT ce.plaçes, ce.mesos, ce.període , un.nomUniversitat ,un.idUniversitat,co.codiConveni, eu.nomGrau
                                        FROM professorscentre pr, centreestudis ce, universitat_estudisuab ue, estudisuab eu, universitats un, conveni co
                                        WHERE pr.niuProfessor = ?
                                        AND ce.codiCentreEstudis = pr.codiCentreEstudis
                                        AND ue.codiEstudis = eu.codiEstudis
                                        AND ce.codiUniEstudis = ue.codiUniEstudis
                                        AND un.idUniversitat = ue.idUniversitat
                                        AND co.codiCentreEstudis = ce.codiCentreEstudis
                                        ORDER BY un.nomUniversitat');
        $consulta->execute(array($niu));
        $obj = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $obj;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: the code of perfil.php would be interesting. Do you return all rows or only the relevant for the page?

Comment: @Bernhard Hi, i added the function perfil.php in the post, so now you can see it. In getConvenis() i return everyting because i need this query for other things, in getAgreementsTeacher() i return the ones i need

Comment: but which of this functions is called with the AJAX call?

Comment: @Bernhard The ajax called to perfil.php and enter into the case 'filtrarAcordsAdmin', this redirects into another controller with the function filtrarAcordsAdmin. This function get some values of the BD thanks of the functions getConvenis() and getAgreementsTeacher(), and shows this results in the view:  $route = $this->view->show("TaulaAcordsCoordinador.php");
    include($route);